# Finding a vector that is perpendicular to a line.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two position vectors $\textbf{a} = (-1,0), \textbf{b} = (1,4)$, and have found the position vector of a general point along the line joining these to points to be $\textbf{r} = (-1+2 \alpha,4\alpha) $.

How would I find a point P on the line such that the position vector of P is perpendicular to the line?

I have taken a general point and formed a dot product, this isn't getting me anywhere.
Im a little bit stumped, even just a small clue would suffice.

ATTEMPT;

the gradient of AB is 2, hence the gradient of the point we require is -1/2. if we set up

$\frac{-1}{2} = \frac{4\alpha}{-1+2\alpha}$

we obtain

$P(-8/10,4/10)$

Comment: what do you know about the gradients of two perpendicular lines?

Comment: if one line has gradient $a$ then a line perpendicular to that line has gradient $-1/a$?

Comment: I think i might have the answer, but the dot product does not come out as 0. between the general point and the point i have found.

Comment: This problem is quite simple if attempted using coordinate geometry. You have a line joining points a and b and all you have to do is find the foot of perpendicular from origin to line ab.

Comment: And a decent diagram should help too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your line is described by $p + \alpha q, \ (\alpha \in \mathbb R)$, a point $v=p + \alpha_0 q$ on the line perpendicular to it should satisfy $0=\langle p+\alpha_0 q,q \rangle = \langle p,q \rangle + \alpha_0 \langle q,q \rangle$ which yields 
$$
\alpha_0 = \frac{-\langle p,q\rangle}{\langle q,q\rangle}.
$$ I use $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ as notation for the inner product of two vectors.

Comment: That looks very familiar to the second term in the Gram-Schmit method for finding orthogonal basis. I think i can see why. sorry, bit random, thanks for the answer though. Could you perhaps point out where my method has gone wrong.

Comment: Gram Schmidt indeed uses projections. Here, you want in particular find the projection of there zero vector onto your line. Your point $P$ is by the way correct. If you use the above method, you find the same point. Here $p$ is the vector $(-1,0)$ and $q$ is $(1,2)$. This gives $\alpha_0 = \frac 15$ and hence $v = (-1,0) + \frac 1 5 (1,2) = (-4/5,2/5) = (-8/10,4,10)$. (I adjusted notation of the inner product in oder to distinguish vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ from the inner product.)